# Images are not showing up when using a button

Tags: xcode, image, swift, tic-tac-toe

When I click run app, the app doesn't place images when I click on the designated buttons. (I am relatively new to Swift and Xcode so bear with me)

I am going to remove the UIImageViews and use buttons instead. I'll let you know if I need more help. Thank you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var TicTacImg1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var TicTacImg9: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var TicTacButton1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var TicTacButton9: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var ResetButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var UserMessage: UILabel!

var plays = Dictionary <Int, Int> ()

@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    UserMessage.hidden = true
    if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }
}

func setImageForSpot (spot:Int, player:Int) {
    var playerMark = player == 1 ? "x" : "o"
    plays[spot] = player
    switch spot {
    case 1:
        TicTacImg1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 2:
        TicTacImg2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 3:
        TicTacImg3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 4:
        TicTacImg4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 5:
        TicTacImg5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 6:
        TicTacImg6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 7:
        TicTacImg7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 8:
        TicTacImg8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 9:
        TicTacImg9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    default:
        TicTacImg5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    }
}
```

Comment: The sigterm when you quit is probably just a side effect of how you have the debugger setup and can be ignored. You might as well edit your question removing that part.

Comment: Is your IBAction executing? Please put an `sprintf()` or set a breakpoint above `UserMessage.hidden = true`.

Comment: Also you're breaking a bunch of long standing conventions (although syntax errors). Your function named `UIButtonClicked` should start with a lowercase character and should not reference being clicked. A better function name would be `tickTacButtonAction:`. Also `UserMessage` should be `userMessage` and `TickTackImg1`(/2/3/4/..) should be `tickTackImg1`. Ditto for the `tickTackButton` variables.

Comment: Also, another thing to double chick, it looks like you have buttons placed over the top of images? Are the buttons opaque or transparent? They might be hiding the image views. I suggest removing the image views altogether, and just placing the image on the `UIButton` views. They can display an image and can be set to hide their border, showing only the image just like a `UIImageView`. Similarly, if  the `UIImageView` is on top of the `UIButton`, then you will not be able to tap on the button, because the tap will go to the image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIButtonClicked function needs to look like this...

```
    @IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
            ticTacLabel.hidden = true
            if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
                setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }
```

Hope this helps!